# Why should we use composer rather than using include_once or require_once?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have searched many blogs and websites but I didn't find any perfect answer.
whenever I use composer I have to include the autoload.php file and then for each class to autoload I have to use that class with the namespace.now I want to know what is the advantage of this composer where I can easily include the class file by include_once or require_once rather than using both autoload.php and the class file individually.
when I use composer I have to write these code:

```
include_once("vendor/autoload.php");
use namespace/derectoryname/classname;
```

whenever I include manually than

```
include_once("classname.php");
```

can anyone clear these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First and foremost, composer main advantage is to handle dependencies (and your dependencies' dependencies, and so on). The autoloader is just frosting on the cake.

The question would be better posed as `include` vs autoloader, and then it gets slightly more interesting.

First, brevity. With one approach you'll end up using two declarations per file: `use` and `include`, whereas using the autoloader you'll just need to declare the `use` statements, and let the autoloader do the dirty work of actually loading the file.

Also, performance. If you `include` or `require` your requirement at the top of your file, you will always load that other file. With the autoloader, you'll only do so if you actually try to use the required class. Until you try to instantiate or use any of the required classes, the autoloader wont hit the filesystem and try to find the required class, making it more efficient, and only doing the work when you actually need the work.

As a somewhat crude example:

```
use Namespace\Package\Service\ServiceProvider
use Namespace\Package\Exception\ServiceProviderException

if (isset($options['service_id'])) {
   try {
      $service = ServiceProvider::getService($options['service_id']);
   }
   catch (ServiceProviderException $e) {
       // do your exception handling
   }
}
else {
   // and now for something entirely different
}
```

With this, the file that declares `ServiceProvider` is only going to get loaded if you actually meet the requirements, and the file that declares `ServiceProviderException` only when if you have to catch the exception (although to be fair it would have been included by the autoloader when `ServiceProvider` needed to `throw` that exception, and not before).

On top of that, you've got a neater separation of concerns. Your ClassA that needs to `use NameSpace\Package\ClassB` is not required to know where you are actually storing that file. It's not its job, and shouldn't care about the actual structure of the filesystem, making the code more portable. Someone somewhere else might have a different `vendor` structure than you and still get use your code easily if it uses an autoloader, instead of hardcoding file paths in your `require` statements.

This should be more or less enough to show you that autoloading is a much more modern, efficient, and portable way to work than `including` your requirements manually.

And since you are already using composer to handle your dependencies, which is **awesome**, you get the autoloader benefits for free!